# Powershell parameter handling

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that looks something like this.

```
Function Write-DeploymentConf {
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateLength(4, 15)]
        [String]
        $CustomerName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateLength(4, 15)]
        [String]
        $FacilityName = $CustomerName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateLength(5, 1024)]
        [String]
        $LocationAddress,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet("onpremise", "cloud")]
        [String]
        $DeploymentMode = "onpremise"
    )
    Process {
        $( Write-Host "CustomerName: $CustomerName")
        $( Write-Host "FacilityName: $FacilityName")
        $( Write-Host "LocationAddress: $LocationAddress")
        $( Write-Host "DeploymentMode: $DeploymentMode")
    }

}

Write-DeploymentConf
```

It's close to what I want, but there are a few things wrong with it.

1. It silently accepts inputs that will fail validation, then holds them until the user has entered values for every parameter, then dies with an error message. I don't want to die, I just want to re-prompt when validation fails. And, ideally, I want to re-prompt right away, not after everything has been input. I only want to re-prompt for ones that failed validation.
2. I want to tell the user what the validation rules are before they mess it up. If the only allowable values are "onpremise" or "cloud", then the user should be told that. Ideally the user should just type "1, enter" for "onpremise", "2, enter" for "cloud".
3. Some parameters have a reasonable default that I want to prompt the user to accept. For example, if `$CustomerName` is "abcd", then "abcd" is a reasonable default value for `$FacilityName`. When prompting `$FacilityName`, I want to allow the user to change it, or press "enter" to accept "abcd" as the default. Not only do I want to accept that as a default, but I want to *show* that the 'abcd' will be the default value on the prompt line. Likewise, "onpremise" is a reasonable default for `$DeploymentMode`, but I want them to affirmatively accept that default.
4. Some sets of parameters are only conditionally mandatory. E.g., if this is a cloud deploy, then a bunch of credentials become mandatory to supply. Can I keep the nice "accept from command line but fall back to prompting" behavior with runtime conditionals?

Comment: On SO, you should [ask] one question per post. With that said. For points 1,2,3, the short answer is that's not how parameter validation works. If you want to make custom logic in your function to check parameters and prompt users, then you'll need to use some ugly `Read-Host`s. Point 4, use a [Parameter set.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/06/30/use-parameter-sets-to-simplify-powershell-commands/). But really if your users need to run a PowerShell function, then give them a good help section. If you need to hold their hand through the process, then `Read-Host` away.

Comment: Thanks! I think of these as one question, which you were able to answer with one answer ("Gotta use `Read-Host` after all"). I just wanted to make sure I'm not reinventing a wheel.

Comment: @BenH is right. In addition, if you must use `Read-Host`, separate the function that does the work (with its parameters and validation) from the part that does the prompting; make it a separate function. This give you a reusable piece of code that can be used completely programmatically, and the user interface part is a separate piece that collects info and calls the real function. [Splatting will help with that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting).

Comment: If you want to hold the user's hand this much you may want to consider creating a GUI for your script. It's probably easier than you think, check out [this](https://foxdeploy.com/series/learning-gui-toolmaking-series/) guide from FoxDeploy.